# enhance name attribute in a form

Tags: javascript, jquery, django-forms

I have a form, and add dynamically fields to it. After adding the fields I want to enhance the name attribute in the way that this:

```
<form id="workshops" action="" method="post">
  <input type="hidden" value="1" name="form-0-Workshops">
  <input type="hidden" value="morning" name="form-0-Day">
  <input type="hidden" value="3" name="form-0-Workshops">
  <input type="hidden" value="evening" name="form-0-Day">
  <input type="hidden" value="3" name="form-0-Workshops">
  <input type="hidden" value="morning" name="form-0-Day">
</form>
```

Becomes:

```
<form id="workshops" action="" method="post">
  <input type="hidden" value="1" name="form-0-Workshops">
  <input type="hidden" value="morning" name="form-0-Day">
  <input type="hidden" value="3" name="form-1-Workshops">
  <input type="hidden" value="evening" name="form-1-Day">
  <input type="hidden" value="3" name="form-2-Workshops">
  <input type="hidden" value="morning" name="form-2-Day">
</form>
```

I have this to start with but I don't make any progress.....

```
var forms = $('form#workshops input[name$="Workshops"]');

for (var i=0, formCount=forms.length; i<formCount; i++){
    $('form#workshops input[name$="Workshops"]').each(function() {
        //$(this) seems to be empty    
    });
}
```

Comment: try this `$('form#workshops').find('input[name="form-0-Workshops"],input[name="form-0-Day"]')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code keeps re-selecting things inside of a loop. Makes no sense.

Use each to your advantage, it gives you the index so there is no need to do the for loop. .

```
function rename (i) {
    var parts = this.name.split("-");
    parts[1] = i;
    this.name = parts.join("-");
}

var form = $("#workshops");
form.find('input[name$="Workshops"]').each(rename);
form.find('input[name$="Day"]').each(rename);
```

Comment: didnt know I could numerate through each(). I was just struggling with the double loop.

Answer (score 1):

Try using this:

```
// Get all the forms inputs
var $forms = $('form#workshops input[name$="Workshops"]');

// Loop through each form inputs
$forms.each(function () {
    console.log($(this));
});
```

Comment: a +1 for the console.log much better then the alerts. The selection is working properly. When I did an alert($(this).html()) the output was empty.

Comment: Are you looking for the `form` html?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe just try :

```
$('#workshops input[name$="Workshops"]').each(function() { /*...*/ });
```

Comment: This won't work : `^=` is for the beginning (see for example : http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp) and here we are looking to the end of the name...

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following code:

```
var forms_input = $('form#workshops input[name *="Workshops"]');

forms_input.each(function() {
    console.log($(this))
});
```